# How to override child element attributes with parent .class attributes

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

I'm developing an app and having some trouble overriding the `background-position` attribute. In the app, I'm adding a class `font-size-big` to the `html` element to increase the font-size. Doing this, my custom underline image's position becomes to low. The underline now floats over the link text.

What I want to achieve, is having different `background-position`s for each font-size class (font-size-big, font-size-small, font-size-medium). It seems like I can't select the `a` element depending on the `html` elements class.

HTML:

```
<html class="font-size-big">
  <head></head>
  <body class="article">
    <section class="links">From <a href="http://foo.bar">Steven</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

SCSS:

```
.font-size-big {
  font-size: ($basic-fontsize * 1.2) + rem;;
}

.links {
  color:$grey;
  font: {
    family:$fontTextItalic;
    size: $basic-fontsize;
  }

  a {
    color:$grey;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(/assets/images/article/dottedLinkUnderline_grey.png) repeat-x 0 23;
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time. I'm really stuck on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should have to override the basic style, just because the font size is chaning. What will you do, if the user is forcing an even bigger text size? Your layout will be broken. Instead of giving the underline image an fixed position you should have it in given in percentage.

```
background-position: 0% 100%;
```

Will set the image to the bottom of the element. If you always want to add 23px (which you forgot to define the unit for) you can try something like this:

```
.links a
{
    background-position:0 calc(100% + 23px); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick. I used `background-position: 0 1rem`, which works equally well.